# Custom Dialog Box

Tags: delphi

Trying to get a custom dialogbox to work with the button names weapon1  , weapon2, and cancel. But with this code it is giving error on Result as undefined when i try to compile it
The error message is

> [DCC Error] ssClientHost.pas(760): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Result'

The code is :

```
      with CreateMessageDialog('Pick What Weapon', mtConfirmation,mbYesNoCancel) do
       try
           TButton(FindComponent('Yes')).Caption := Weapon1;
           TButton(FindComponent('No')).Caption := Weapon2;
           Position := poScreenCenter;
           Result := ShowModal;
        finally
     Free;
   end;
     if buttonSelected = mrYes    then ShowMessage('Weapon 1 pressed');
     if buttonSelected = mrAll    then ShowMessage('Weapon 2 pressed');
     if buttonSelected = mrCancel then ShowMessage('Cancel pressed');
```

Comment: Is 'Result' undefined or is 'ShowModal' undefined?

Comment: [DCC Error] ssClientHost.pas(760): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Result'

Comment: Then you are not in a function. Result is the result of a function, it has no meaning in a procedure so its not available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code posted above has a lot of errors, unless there are parts you are not showing us. For one thing, if there are no string variables `Weapon1` and `Weapon2`, then you cannot refer to such variables! Second, if there is no `Result` variable (there is if the code is inside a function, for instance), then that's an error, too. Also, in your code above, `buttonSelected` is a variable, which you might have forgotten to declare as well. Finally, first you talk about `Yes` and `No`, then you talk about `Yes` and `Yes to all`.

The following code works (standalone):

```
with CreateMessageDialog('Please pick a weapon:', mtConfirmation, mbYesNoCancel) do
  try
    TButton(FindComponent('Yes')).Caption := 'Weapon1';
    TButton(FindComponent('No')).Caption := 'Weapon2';
    case ShowModal of
      mrYes: ShowMessage('Weapon 1 selected.');
      mrNo: ShowMessage('Weapon 2 selected.');
      mrCancel: ShowMessage('Cancel pressed.')
    end;
finally
  Free;
end;
```

*Disclaimer: The author of this answer is not fond of weapons.*

Comment: I like the disclaimer ;-).

Comment: Ahh got ya, thanks for help the weapons are defined elsewhere, and using case instead of result  works great! ..Also its weapons for a game ;D

Answer (score 1):

Result is only defined in a function:

```
function TMyObject.DoSomething: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;

procedure TMyObject.DoSomethingWrong;
begin
  Result := True;    // Error!
end;
```

So, you get something like:

```
function TMyForm.PickYourWeapon(const Weapon1, Weapon2: string): TModalResult;
begin
  with CreateMessageDialog('Pick What Weapon', mtConfirmation,mbYesNoCancel) do
    try
      TButton(FindComponent('Yes')).Caption := Weapon1;
      TButton(FindComponent('No')).Caption := Weapon2;
      Position := poScreenCenter;
      Result := ShowModal;
   finally
     Free;
   end;
   // Debug code?
{$IFDEF DEBUG)
   if Result = mrYes then 
     ShowMessage('Weapon 1 pressed');
   if Result = mrAll then 
     ShowMessage('Weapon 2 pressed');
   if Result = mrCancel then 
     ShowMessage('Cancel pressed');
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

Comment: now that i think about it, i knew that :D ... but this code was posted as an example of using CreateMessageDialog.  I am confused on something here.